# Is there a program to remove trailing spaces and convert tabs to spaces in a lot of files at once using command-line?

Tags: cygwin

I am using cygwin and have a lot of files in which I want to convert tabs to spaces and remove all space characters that exist at end of line. Is there a utility for this in Linux?

Comment: Although this question is off-topic on this site, with a little improvement it will be on-topic on Software Recommendations SE: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Tabs to spaces: `expand`.

Remove spaces at the end of lines: I would probably use `sed 's/ *$//'`, but perhaps there is a tool that is focused on exactly that task.

Both are available in Cygwin or any version of UNIX and Linux.

Comment: I know about program called sed but what is expand?

Comment: Can't sed be used for both purposes?

Comment: `expand` expands tabs. Use `man expand`. I would not know how to use `sed` to correctly expand tabs. The number of spaces by which a tab is replaced depends on the position of the tab in the line; this is very hard to do with `sed`, in my opinion. If you want a single tool for both tasks, I suggest `awk`, but expanding tabs is not quite trivial.

Comment: Shouldn't it must be that replace tab with 4 spaces?

Comment: If that's what you want, `sed` is fine. However, this is not tab expansion.

Answer (score 1):

Tiny file using TAB, using `od` to see the content

```
$ od -c file.txt
0000000  \t   o   n   e  \t  \t   t   w   o  \n
```

using sed to replace the TAB `\t` with 4 spaces

```
$ sed -i -e "s/\t/    /g" file.txt
```

the files is now longer and all TAB replaced

```
$ od -c file.txt
0000000                   o   n   e                                   t
0000020   w   o  \n
0000023
0000012
```

you can apply the same to multiple files.
Further reading for learning Sed
https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html